# Several errors "Access of undefined property"

Tags: actionscript-3, addeventlistener, stage

So I have this pretty basic code in my document class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        //Properties
        public var circle:Circle;
        public var vx:Number;
        public var vy:Number;   
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyboardDown);
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyboardUp);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
        public function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {

        }
        public function Main()
        {
            super();
            init();
        }
        public function init():void
        {
            vx = 0;
            vy = 0;

            circle = new Circle(35, 0x0066FF);
            stage.addChild(circle);
            circle.x = 50;
            circle.y = 50;          


        }
        public function onKeyboardDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch(event.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.LEFT:
                vx = -5;
                break;
                case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                vx = 5;
                break;
                case Keyboard.UP:
                vy = -5;
                break;
                case Keyboard.DOWN:
                vy = 5;
                break;
            }
        }
        public function onKeyboardUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch(event.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.LEFT:
                vx = 0;
                break;
                case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                vx = 0;
                break;
                case Keyboard.UP:
                vy = 0;
                break;
                case Keyboard.DOWN:
                vy = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        public function onEnter(event:Event):void
        {
            circle.x += vx;
            circle.y += vy;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting errors that to a beginner don't make any sense:

"Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener." x 3
"Access of undefined property onEnter."
"Access of undefined property onKeyboardUp."
"Access of undefined property onKeyboardDown."

I really don't understand this issue. How can AS3 not recognize addEventListener? As well, I did have it so my event listeners were added to the stage "stage.addEventListener" and it wasn't recognizing the stage either. Can somebody push me in the right direction with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Your event listeners need to be added AFTER the class has been added to stage. You do not have access to stage events unless the class is added to the display list. In this case Main class should be set as the document class. You need something along the lines of this.addEventListener( EVENT.AddedToStage, addedToStage ).

Comment: Ok, I sort of get it. But then what code should I write for the parameter "addedToStage"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All in all your code is almost there you just need a little bit better understanding on how the display list works.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        //Properties
        public var circle:Circle;
        public var vx:Number;
        public var vy:Number;

       // we can not do function calls like this in the class declaration area
       // so we move these listeners to a function
       // addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyboardDown);
       // addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyboardUp);
       // addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);

        public function Main()
        {
            super();
            this.init();
        }
        public function init():void
        {
            // the "this" keyword means we are scoping it to this class instance 
            this.addEventListener( EVENT.ADDEDTOSTAGE, addedToStageHandler)

            // using "this" is good practice and will help make your code more readable
            this.vx = 0;
            this.vy = 0;

            this.circle = new Circle(35, 0x0066FF);
            stage.addChild(circle);
            this.circle.x = 50;
            this.circle.y = 50;          


        }
        public function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            // doing addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyboardDown);
            // will set the scope for this listener to this class
            // you want to target the stage. And since we are waiting for ADDEDTOSTAGE
            // to trigger we know we are on the stage.
            // the only time we can access stage is if we are on the display list.

            // clean up the listener since we do not need it anymore
            this.removeEventListener( EVENT.ADDEDTOSTAGE, addedToStageHandler)

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyboardDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyboardUp);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);

        }
        public function onKeyboardDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch(event.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.LEFT:
                  this.vx = -5;
                  break;
                case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                  this.vx = 5;
                  break;
                case Keyboard.UP:
                  this.vy = -5;
                  break;
                case Keyboard.DOWN:
                  this.vy = 5;
                  break;
            }
        }
        public function onKeyboardUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch(event.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.LEFT:
                  this.vx = 0;
                  break;
                case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                  this.vx = 0;
                  break;
                case Keyboard.UP:
                  this.vy = 0;
                  break;
                case Keyboard.DOWN:
                  this.vy = 0;
                  break;
            }
        }
        public function onEnter(event:Event):void
        {
            this.circle.x += this.vx;
            this.circle.y += this.vy;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! There's only one issue with your code (besides ADDEDTOSTAGE needing to be changed to ADDED_TO_STAGE ;)); when I run your edit, I get an error saying that it is expecting an identifier before super at line 26. Any idea what to do with this?

Comment: Hi, so I removed "this.super();" from my code and now it works fine; what exactly does super do? Is it considered bad practice to not use it? Any workaround to using it without getting a compiler error? Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah it should have been just super() not this.super() what super does is calls the constructor of the base class IE: the class you are extending. It is good practice to always call super just in case there is some code in the base class constructor that sets up the class.

Answer (score 1):

It's logic because you'll have to place the eventListeners inside the ´init´ method or Class constructor.

```
public function init():void
{
    addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyboardDown);
    addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyboardUp);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);

    vx = 0;
    vy = 0;

    circle = new Circle(35, 0x0066FF);
    stage.addChild(circle);
    circle.x = 50;
    circle.y = 50;         
}
```

If not the listeners are placed outside the class scope, and therefor not recognized.

Good luck!

Comment: When I did that, I got even more errors! Thanks for trying though :).

Comment: What errors? The above code is fine as long as there is functions named onKeyboardDown,onKeyboardUp and onEnter which you have in your question.

Comment: I have that function in the code along with the same exact code as before, and I'm getting 20 errors which are all instances of "Access of undefined property vx" or vy or circle.